# Callback загрузки карты yandex map

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Имеется пустая страница с картой для печати. С помощью `window.print()` вызывается на печать. Проблема заключается в том, что карта не успевает отрисоваться. Никак не могу нагуглить и нарыть в их замечательной документации какой-то вариант события или callback'a именно на готовность карты.

Есть предложения, коллеги?

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var map,
    object;

  function init() {
    var center = settings.map.center,
      zoom = parseInt(settings.map.zoom),
      coords_point = settings.map.coords_point;

    center = center.split(',').map(parseFloat);
    coords_point = coords_point.split(',').map(parseFloat);

    map = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
      center: center,
      zoom: zoom,
      controls: [],
    });

    object = new ymaps.GeoObject({
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: coords_point
      },
    }, {
      preset: 'custom#point_green',
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(object);
  }

  ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('custom#point_green', {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: settings.themePath + '/img/yamap_point_g.png',
    iconImageSize: [48, 41],
    iconImageOffset: [-15, -41],
    hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  });
});
```

**Обновление**

Пример вызова `window.print()`:

[Пример на JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2an9kz4a/1/)

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var map,
    object;

  function init() {
    var center = "56.83676954481658,60.61677207117298",
      zoom = 15,
      coords_point = "56.836098132297586,60.61771118192043";

    center = center.split(',').map(parseFloat);
    coords_point = coords_point.split(',').map(parseFloat);

    map = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
      center: center,
      zoom: zoom,
      controls: [],
    });

    object = new ymaps.GeoObject({
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: coords_point
      },
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(object);
  }
});

window.print();
```

```css
#yamap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="yamap"></div>
```

Comment: А если через таймаут? К примеру `setTimeout(window.print, 3000);` Написать в конце функции `init`. Или это плохо?

Comment: Можно конечно, но 3 секунды не гарантируют загрузки, это будет костыль. Например, на медленном интернете это может занять больше времени.

Comment: @Alex, @Valkilaz  знаю, что решение с таймаутом не самое элегантное и выглядит как костыль, но что-то мне подсказывает, что по другому вряд ли получится. Если только юзера самого заставить потом рукой нажать кнопку `распечатать`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  что ж, пожалуй, обговорим момент с проект-менеджером. Теперь я вижу решение только действительно сделать с кнопкой и лишним кликом. Причем, кнопку как управляющий элемент самой карты, чтобы быть уверенным в загрузке.

Comment: @Alex, благодарю за ссылку, не натыкался.

Comment: а если на `window.load` повесить `print`?

Comment: @xaja, пробовал, так и вешал изначально.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поместите хотя бы `window.print()` внутрь `ymaps.ready()` и вместо `ymaps.ready(init)` вызывайте просто `init()`.

**Дополнено**

Событий, однозначно показывающих полное окончание всех процедур составления карты пока нет. Однако, как показывает практика, загрузка карты заканчивается загрузкой всех тайлов. И в документации есть описание как можно добавлять новые слои с тайлами. Это делается при помощи классов [layer.tileContainer.CanvasContainer](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layer.tileContainer.CanvasContainer-docpage/) и [layer.tileContainer.DomContainer](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layer.tileContainer.DomContainer-docpage/). У этих-то классов есть событие `ready`, которое вызывается когда все тайлы слоя загружены. И они даже используются при отображении карт, но до их экземпляра не так просто добраться.

Если вы ничего не делаете со слоями, то на карте есть один единственный слой (если слоев все-таки несколько, придется обрабатывать все слои в циклах), к которому можно достучаться вот так

```
var layer = map.layers.get(0).get(0);
/* Сначала мы получаем первый экземпляр коллекции слоев, потом первый слой коллекции */
```

Так мы получаем экземпляр [Layer](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/), но в его описании нету ничего про `tileContainer`, однако это поле там есть, только оно как бы приватное и при минимизации становится неудобоваримым (в debug версии это поле `_tileContainer`). Чтобы его найти можно воспользоваться вот такой функцией:

```
function getTileContainer(layer) {
    for (var k in layer) {
        if (layer.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (
                layer[k] instanceof ymaps.layer.tileContainer.CanvasContainer
                || layer[k] instanceof ymaps.layer.tileContainer.DomContainer
            ) {
                return layer[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Теперь можно сделать так:

```
var tc = getTileContainer(layer);
tc.events.once("ready", function() {
    // Вызываем, например, печать документа window.print();
});
```

Одно плохо. Мы не узнаем о загрузке всех тайлов если выяснится, что мы не успели начать слушать событие до окончания загрузки тайлов. Неплохо было бы знать вообще чего-то ждем или нет. Для этого перед "подслушиванием" события нужно узнать есть-ли "неготовые" тайлы. Это можно проверить если перебрать все тайлы в контейнере и вызвать методы `isReady()` для [layer.tile.CanvasTile](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ICanvasTile-docpage/#isReady) или [layer.tile.DomTile](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IDomTile-docpage/#isReady), после этого, если неготовые тайлы есть подключать событие. Будет удобно сделать такую функцию, которая будет возвращать промис.

```
function waitForTilesLoad(layer) {
    return new ymaps.vow.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var tc = getTileContainer(layer), readyAll = true;
        tc.tiles.each(function (tile, number) {
            if (!tile.isReady()) {
                readyAll = false;
            }
        });
        if (readyAll) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            tc.events.once("ready", function() {
                resolve();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

В вашем случае этой функцией можно воспользоваться так:

```
waitForTilesLoad(layer).then(function() {
    window.print();
});
```

Comment: Увы, в таком варианте сама карта с меткой все равно не успевает появиться. Только копирайт, ссылка на яндекс и их логотип вместо карты.

Comment: @Valkinaz Я тут немного покопался в исходниках и дополнил ответ. Вроде работает :\

Comment: интересное решение, действительно работает :) Браво, и спасибо)

Comment: @tutankhamun, спасибо за решение. После перехода карт на 2 версию layer.tileContainer.DOMContainer переименовался в layer.tileContainer.DomContainer. Приведу ниже получившийся код для будущих разработок.

Comment: @CoolMind Дело не в версии. Это просто моя ошибка :) Я же даже ссылку привел

Comment: @tutankhamun, эх, а я тогда не заметил... Спасибо за правки.

Answer (score 0):

Привожу код, написанный @tutankhamun.

```
        // Здесь ваша загрузка карты. Ниже допишем строки.

        /* Поймаем событие завершения загрузки карты. */
        // Сначала мы получаем первый экземпляр коллекции слоев, потом первый слой коллекции.
        var layer = myMap.layers.get(0).get(0);
        // Отслеживаем событие окончания отрисовки тайлов.
        waitForTilesLoad(layer).then(function() {
            // Вызываем, например, печать документа window.print();
            alert('Карта загружена');
        });
    }

    // Получить слой, содержащий тайлы.
    function getTileContainer(layer) {
        for (var k in layer) {
            if (layer.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                if (
                    layer[k] instanceof ymaps.layer.tileContainer.CanvasContainer
                    || layer[k] instanceof ymaps.layer.tileContainer.DomContainer
                ) {
                    return layer[k];
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Определить, все ли тайлы загружены. Возвращает Promise.
    function waitForTilesLoad(layer) {
        return new ymaps.vow.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var tc = getTileContainer(layer), readyAll = true;
            tc.tiles.each(function (tile, number) {
                if (!tile.isReady()) {
                    readyAll = false;
                }
            });
            if (readyAll) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                tc.events.once("ready", function() {
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```