# Как вывести на печать Яндекс.Карту?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

На сайте есть Яндекс.Карты с маршрутом, созданным через API. Нужно вывести её на печать.

Как лучше всего сделать? Сам думаю делать, получив картинку через статический API Яндекс.Карт, но никак не могу получить из карты вершины ломанной линии маршрута.

Код очень грязный, но рабочий:

```html
<a id="map-img" class="btn btn-success">На печать</a>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    $('#map-img').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // var win = window.open();
      // win.document.write("<img src='"+$(this).attr('href')+"'>");
      // console.log("<img src='"+$(this).attr('href')+"'>");
      window.print();
    });
  };
</script>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px"></div>

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU&coordorder=longlat" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var myMap;
  var cleaner_addr = "<?php  echo('Москва, Нагатинская ул., 1c23');?>";
  var client_addr = "<?php  echo('Москва, ул. Льва Толстого, 16');?>";

  function init() {
    cleaner_geocode = ymaps.geocode(cleaner_addr, {
      "json": true
    });
    cleaner_geocode.then(
      function(res) {

        var cleaner_coords = res.GeoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.GeocoderResponseMetaData.Point.coordinates;
        console.log(cleaner_coords);
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
          center: cleaner_coords,
          zoom: 12
        });
        myMap.controls.add(
          new ymaps.control.ZoomControl()
        );

        var cleanerPM = new ymaps.Placemark(cleaner_coords, {
          hintContent: '1',
          balloonContent: 'Столица России'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(cleanerPM);
        var metro_geocode = ymaps.geocode(cleaner_coords, {
          "json": true,
          "kind": "metro",
          "multiRoute": true,
          "routingMode": "masstransit"
        });
        metro_geocode.then(
          function(res) {



            metro_coords = res.GeoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.GeocoderResponseMetaData.Point.coordinates;
            console.log(cleaner_coords);
            var client_geocode = ymaps.geocode(client_addr, {
              "json": true
            });

            client_geocode.then(
              function(res) {
                client_coords = res.GeoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.GeocoderResponseMetaData.Point.coordinates;

                ymaps.route([
                  cleaner_coords,
                  metro_coords,
                  client_coords
                ]).then(
                  function(route) {

                    myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
                    console.log(route.getPaths().geometry);
                    var coords = cleaner_coords.join(',') + ',' + metro_coords.join(',') + ',' + client_coords.join(',');
                    $('#map-img').attr('href', 'https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&pl=' + coords);

                  },
                  function(error) {
                    alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
                  }
                );


              },
              function(err) {
                // обработка ошибки
              }
            );







          },
          function(err) {
            // обработка ошибки
          }
        );

















      },
      function(err) {
        // обработка ошибки
      }
    );






  }
</script>
```

Comment: Как вы получаете маршрут? По идее, с вершинами проблем быть не должно.

Comment: с помощью ymaps.route , но я не понял как получать координаты

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Постарайтесь не делать таких конструкций `do().then(function() { do().then(); }` или выстраивайте цепочку [промисов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/util.Promise-docpage/) или параллельно выполняйте запросы (в данном случае это оправдано)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Откройте карту в новой странице;
2. [Дождитесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463666/177613) загрузки карты;
3. Вызовите `window.print()`;

**Дополнено**

Получить координаты маршрута можно примерно так:

```
ymaps.route(coords).then(function(route) {
    route.getPaths().each(function(path) {
        console.log(path.geometry.getCoordinates());
    });
});
```

PS. Статический API крайне урезан в функциональности.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так, не отображаются метки, но хотя бы с маршрутом все ок.

Comment: @dergus Почему не отображаются метки? Дополните ваш вопрос хотя бы фрагментом кода

Comment: код ну очень плохой, ибо пока тестю это не финальная версия и писал быстро, но ок добавлю