# Событие окончания прорисовки объектов на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Добрый день.

Объекты на карте добавляются в ymaps.ObjectManager, используя JSON:

```
ObjectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager
(
    {
        clusterize: true,
        gridSize: 32,
        hasBalloon: true,
        hasHint: true,
        minClusterSize: 5
    }
);
```

Через ObjectManager.add(json).

Объектов очень много и от процесса старта добавления до момента прорисовки объектов на карте со своими рисунками проходит секунды 3-4.

Каким образом можно отловить событие окончания прорисовки объектов на карте, чтобы пока она загружались показывать на карте процесс загрузки?

Comment: Есть костыль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463666/177613, но он касается подгрузки тайлов, если покопаться в коде, наверняка можно найти способ поймать и загрузку объектов

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, я разработчик jsapi яндекс.карт. Сейчас таких событий нет, но мы запомнили фичреквест, подумаем над добавлением таких событий в будущих релизах.